# How Do I Quickly Merge A Large Amount Of Cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, concatenate

So I'm trying to merge all cells in Col A and B so that A1 and B1 are one cell all the way for 150 rows, anybody knows how?

Comment: 1-cell like one cell or one cell per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:B150), , 999^99)), , 999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:B150), , 999^99))
```

[image: 0]